# Reactive REST (webflux) in google appengine: How to deploy?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, spring-webflux, reactive

I have a REACTIVE-rest  application, that uses springboot webflux. Uses jetty for backend.

How do I expose flux and mono rest endpoints through Appengine? Is there a way to do it?

Does google appengine support its own reactive-java based api endpoints?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just deploy it the way you would normally deploy your application. App engine is just managed kubernetes. And therefore what is providing you is not a costume runtime but just Operating System (some lightweight version of Linux from Google.) and ability to scale, networking, security.

The reactive rest part comes from 2 things:

**Number 1** how OS (any OS, windows does it too) do I/O operations (redding/writing from sockets, reading/writing from disk etc.) and they are inherently asynchronous.

**Number 2** how java interacts with I/O. And until Java 7 came out they were artificially blocked by the Java Runtime. Java 7 introduced NIO (Non Blocking I/O). That gave java programmer ability to interact with I/O multiplexer via select() and poll() methods.

Servers like netty are using that API to stop this one thread per request model that was such a bottleneck for scaling. 
You have to be careful though because Tomcat still uses the old ways. That why default http server for the spring-webflux project is netty while for spring-mvc is tomcat.

Bottom line app engine changes nothing if you deploy your app to any os that supports NIO you are good to go.